# Get Layer2 Text (Signature Description) from signature image using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need to retrieve the layer2 text from a signature. How can I get the description (under the signature image) using itextsharp? below is the code I'm using to get the sign date and username:

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MASTER_PDF_PASSWORD));
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);
            AcroFields acroFields = stamper.AcroFields;
            List<String> names = acroFields.GetSignatureNames();
            foreach (String name in names)
            {
                PdfPKCS7 pk = acroFields.VerifySignature(name);
                String userName = PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields(pk.SigningCertificate).GetField("CN");
                Console.WriteLine("Sign Date: " + pk.SignDate.ToString() + " Name: " + userName);
               // Here i need to retrieve the description underneath the signature image
            }
            reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
            reader.Close();
            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            if (stamper != null)
            {
                stamper.Close();
            }
        }
```

and below is the code I used to set the description

```
PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, memoryStream, '\0', null, true);
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
sap.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.GraphicAndDescription;
sap.Layer2Font = font;
sap.Layer2Text = "Some text that i want to retrieve";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Bruno addressed the issue starting with a PDF containing a "layer 2", allow me to first state that **using these "signature layers" in PDF signature appearances is *not* required by the PDF specification**, the specification actually does not even know these layers at all! Thus, if you try to parse a specific layer, you may not find such a "layer" or, even worse, find something that looks like that layer (a XObject named **n2**) which contains the wrong data.

That been said, though, Whether you look for text from a layer 2 or from the signature appearance as a whole, you can use iTextSharp text extraction capabilities. I used Bruno's code as base for retrieving the **n2** layer.

```
public static void ExtractSignatureTextFromFile(FileInfo file)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Out.Write("File: {0}\n", file);
        using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(file.FullName))
        {
            AcroFields fields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
            foreach (string name in fields.GetSignatureNames())
            {
                Console.Out.Write("  Signature: {0}\n", name);
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item item = fields.GetFieldItem(name);
                PdfDictionary widget = item.GetWidget(0);
                PdfDictionary ap = widget.GetAsDict(PdfName.AP);
                if (ap == null)
                    continue;
                PdfStream normal = ap.GetAsStream(PdfName.N);
                if (normal == null)
                    continue;
                Console.Out.Write("    Content of normal appearance: {0}\n", extractText(normal));

                PdfDictionary resources = normal.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
                if (resources == null)
                    continue;
                PdfDictionary xobject = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
                if (xobject == null)
                    continue;
                PdfStream frm = xobject.GetAsStream(PdfName.FRM);
                if (frm == null)
                    continue;
                PdfDictionary res = frm.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
                if (res == null)
                    continue;
                PdfDictionary xobj = res.GetAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
                if (xobj == null)
                    continue;
                PRStream n2 = (PRStream) xobj.GetAsStream(PdfName.N2);
                if (n2 == null)
                    continue;
                Console.Out.Write("    Content of normal appearance, layer 2: {0}\n", extractText(n2));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.Write("Error... " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}

public static String extractText(PdfStream xObject)
{
    PdfDictionary resources = xObject.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

    PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(strategy);
    processor.ProcessContent(ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesFromContentObject(xObject), resources);
    return strategy.GetResultantText();
}
```

For the sample file [signature_n2.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/signature_n2.pdf) Bruno used you get this:

```
File: ...\signature_n2.pdf
  Signature: Signature1
    Content of normal appearance: This document was signed by Bruno
Specimen.
    Content of normal appearance, layer 2: This document was signed by Bruno
Specimen.
```

As this sample uses the layer 2 as the OP expects, it already contains the text in question.

Comment: True, but if you read the second part of the question, you'll see that the signature is created using iText and that layer 2 is explicitly used. Hence you know that n2 is present and you know that the `String`s aren't hexadecimal.

Comment: You are right indeed... I didn't read the fine print in the question.

Comment: But your answer is much better than mine for other people who might have the same question ;-)

Comment: yeah @mkl 's answer is straightforward and a safer bet (no need to parse the string anymore). Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following PDF: [signature_n2.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/signature_n2.pdf). It contains a signature with the following text in the n2 layer:

```
This document was signed by Bruno
Specimen.
```

Before we can write code to extract this text, we should use [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) to look at the internal structure of the PDF, so that we can find out where this `/n2` layer is stored:

[image]

Based on this information, we can start writing our code. See the [GetN2fromSig](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/security/GetN2fromSig) example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
    Item item = fields.getFieldItem("Signature1");
    PdfDictionary widget = item.getWidget(0);
    PdfDictionary ap = widget.getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
    PdfStream normal = ap.getAsStream(PdfName.N);
    PdfDictionary resources = normal.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
    PdfDictionary xobject = resources.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
    PdfStream frm = xobject.getAsStream(PdfName.FRM);
    PdfDictionary res = frm.getAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
    PdfDictionary xobj = res.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
    PRStream n2 = (PRStream) xobj.getAsStream(PdfName.N2);
    byte[] stream = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(n2);
    System.out.println(new String(stream));
}
```

We get the widget annotation for the signature field with name `"signature1"`. Based on the info from RUPS, we know that we have to get the resources (`/Resources`) of the normal (`/N`) appearance (`/AP`). In the `/XObjects` dictionary, we'll find a form XObject named `/FRM`. This XObject has in turn also some `/Resources`, more specifically two `/XObject`s, one named `/n0`, the other one named `/n2`.

We get the stream of the `/n2` object and we convert it to an uncompressed `byte[]`. When we print this array as a `String`, we get the following result:

```
BT
1 0 0 1 0 49.55 Tm
/F1 12 Tf
(This document was signed by Bruno)Tj
1 0 0 1 0 31.55 Tm
(Specimen.)Tj
ET
```

This is PDF syntax. `BT` and `ET` stand for "Begin Text" and "End Text". The `Tm` operator set the text matrix. The `Tf` operator set the font. `Tj` shows the strings that are delimited by `(` and `)`. If you want the plain text, it's sufficient to extract only the text that is between parentheses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer, this is exactly what I needed! In some cases, getting the text between parenthesis might not be enough (I've found some empty parenthesis that I had to omit), so some extra string manipulation is needed.

Comment: @Dory.H *getting the text between parenthesis might not be enough* - depending on the encoding of the font used, you may get something undecipherable. For general use one should use a proper parser.