# Extract Signature Details from Signed Pdf

Tags: itext

This is the signature i got when i am signing a pdf

[image: This is the signature i got when i am signing a pdf]

From which, is there any way to get Signatory(in my Signature Suniiii). Now I am able to extract location, date and Reason except Signatory.

Comment: That information is stored in the certificate. Extract the certificate and examine it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the image you see includes textual information which can be freely chosen by the signing application. Usually for such visualizations the text is chosen to match the information invisibly stored in the signature field but some mischievous signer may insert differences. Thus, you first have to decide whether you want to get the text from the signature appearance or the values stored invisibly in the field.

- If you want to read the exact text from the visualization, simply use the code from the answers to the question ["Get Layer2 Text (Signature Description) from signature image using itextsharp"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30305126/1729265).
- If you want to read the exact content from the invisible field information, use the values of the signature field value dictionary as you already do for location, date, and reason, and also read the CMS signature container from the **Contents**, extract the signer certificate, and read its owner DN.